# Positioning list item numbers by last digit...?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a dynamically generated ordered list with a maximum of 105 items. I'm styling the li numbers with li:before, and everything is fine, but once the list gets to triple digits the numbers begin overlapping with the list items. This obscures the end of the number and part of li itself. What I want to do is have the li numbers be aligned by the last digit as opposed to the first digit. I'm not exactly sure how to ask this, which is probably why I'm having trouble finding an answer. Example below:

How the list item numbers seem to display by default:

```
1.
5.
10.
50.
100.
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
  1.
  5.
 10.
 50.
100.
```

I've experimented a bit with adding

```
direction: rtl
```

and

```
text-align-last: right
```

to the li:before, but neither seem to be doing anything.

Thanks for the help, and sorry if this is a stupid question!

EDIT: here's my css. Thanks!

```
 li:before {
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
   margin-left:-20px;
   margin-top:25px;
   content: counter(item);
   color: white;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size:2rem;
   direction: rtl;
   text-align-last: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post more of your html and css so we can understand exactly what you are doing currently.

By default, an ordered list will right align the item numbers. I have achieved what I think you are after with this:

```css
ol li {
  /* Style the list number */
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol li span {
  /* Style the list item text */
  color: green;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
  <li><span>Item text</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, itodd. I've edited the post with my css for the li item. Thanks!

Comment: For your scenario there is no real need to use the before element, however it can be fixed by adding a width to li:before
(use text-align: right; instead of text-align-last: right; for maximum browser support)

Comment: Yup. That fixed it. I don't think I'll ever be able to make heads or tails of CSS.... Thanks, itodd!!!